# What do I do? Heroku blocked my push even after updating Sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sprockets

Does anyone have any inkling as to what I did wrong or what I should do? I tried pushing after updating Sprockets in my gemfile, but it didn't seem to do anything. Do I need to update sprockets-rails as well too? Even after updating the gemfile the console error didn't seem to change at all. This is the error I get, even after updating sprockets to the recommended version, I even tried to delete and re-bundle the gems.

````
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rails-assets.org/.
remote:        Using rake 12.3.1
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
remote:        Using minitest 5.11.3
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using builder 3.2.3
remote:        Using erubi 1.7.1
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
remote:        Using crass 1.0.4
remote:        Using rack 2.0.5
remote:        Using nio4r 2.3.1
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.0
remote:        Using arel 9.0.0
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.2
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using msgpack 1.2.4
remote:        Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Using ffi 1.9.25
remote:        Using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Using method_source 0.9.0
remote:        Using thor 0.20.0
remote:        Using multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Using pg 0.20.0
remote:        Using puma 3.11.4
remote:        Using rails-assets-particles.js 2.0.0
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.8
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.1.0
remote:        Using i18n 1.0.1
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.8.2
remote:        Using rack-test 1.0.0
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.1
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.7.0
remote:        Using mail 2.7.0
remote:        Using marcel 0.3.2
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 8.6.2
remote:        Using uglifier 4.1.11
remote:        Using bootsnap 1.3.0
remote:        Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.1.1
remote:        Using activesupport 5.2.0
remote:        Using loofah 2.2.2
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.1
remote:        Using activemodel 5.2.0
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.7.0
remote:        Using sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Using activerecord 5.2.0
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
remote:        Using sass 3.5.6
remote:        Using actionview 5.2.0
remote:        Using activejob 5.2.0
remote:        Using actionpack 5.2.0
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
remote:        Using actioncable 5.2.0
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.2.0
remote:        Using activestorage 5.2.0
remote:        Using railties 5.2.0
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.3.1
remote:        Using jquery-ui-rails 6.0.1
remote:        Using rails 5.2.0
remote:        Using rails-ujs 0.1.0
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.7
remote:        Bundle complete! 25 Gemfile dependencies, 67 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (5.93s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        The latest bundler is 1.16.2, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler`
remote: -----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        I, [2018-07-01T05:03:06.512433 #474]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a91e4f1227e923975e3a79b263ebd6a/public/assets/homepage-6506ef98672650880a9829198532c3ca352e86c99fe090e6ab680341ebabb7a0.css
remote:        I, [2018-07-01T05:03:06.512936 #474]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a91e4f1227e923975e3a79b263ebd6a/public/assets/homepage-6506ef98672650880a9829198532c3ca352e86c99fe090e6ab680341ebabb7a0.css.gz
remote:        I, [2018-07-01T05:03:14.402376 #474]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a91e4f1227e923975e3a79b263ebd6a/public/assets/application-257151e69df1b673bb56ffceccaab1209f0d77eb0251792415b789094e1c1214.css
remote:        I, [2018-07-01T05:03:14.403083 #474]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a91e4f1227e923975e3a79b263ebd6a/public/assets/application-257151e69df1b673bb56ffceccaab1209f0d77eb0251792415b789094e1c1214.css.gz
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (10.25s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean
remote: -----> Detecting rails configuration
remote:  !
remote:  !     A security vulnerability has been detected in your application.
remote:  !     To protect your application you must take action. Your application
remote:  !     is currently exposing its credentials via an easy to exploit directory
remote:  !     traversal.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     To protect your application you must either upgrade to Sprockets version "3.7.2"
remote:  !     or disable dynamic compilation at runtime by setting:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     ```
remote:  !     config.assets.compile = false # Disables security vulnerability
remote:  !     ```
remote:  !     
remote:  !     To read more about this security vulnerability please refer to this blog post:
remote:  !     https://blog.heroku.com/rails-asset-pipeline-vulnerability
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
````

Comment: What version of sprockets is in you gem.lock file?  You did run bundle update all that and then push up the code before deploying, correct?

Comment: @Rockwell Rice
`sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)`
This is the what the gemlock file says, I did run bundle update and then push before trying to push to Heroku.

Comment: ok, and that has been pushed up into the repository you are pushing to heroku?

Comment: Im trying to do that but it keeps getting rejected. Does this have to do with that?

Comment: Ok so I am going to assume the repo is on github (bitbucket maybe?).  If you cannot push the updated code to github, then when you push to heroku it is still using the same code base before you updated sprockets.  So right now it sounds like sprockets is only updated on your local copy.  It needs to get pushed up to github.  Then when you push to Heroku it will take that updated code and try to push it to Heroku.  does that make sense?  So if you cannot push to github (or wherever the repo is) then you have to get that fixed first, or you are just pushing the same old code base up to Heroku.

Comment: The odd thing is I can push it github with no problems, the code is on a different branch though. Should I merge it to the main then push the newly merged main to Heroku? Is that what is causing the friction with Heroku? Your answer makes sense. Im new/returning to using RoR so alot has changed within the last couple of years

Comment: Well if you are pushing up the master branch but your code is only updated on "feature_branch_a" (or whatever the name is) then you are just pushing up the old code again.  So yes, that would cause the problem.  You could try "git push heroku *name of branch here*" and try to push up just that branch to test, but you will need to do this to get anything working I suppose so it may be best just to merge, or just update master with the new sprockets level if there is a bunch of work on the branch you do not want to merge

Comment: @RockwellRice, Ill def give that a shot, thank you for being so understanding and helpful!

Comment: @RockwellRice you were right, that cleared it up! Thank you so much for the clear direction and help!